# I need to switch an image that is on one game scene from another game scene in Swift

Tags: ios, image, sprite-kit

I have my Player Defined as an SKSpriteNode and the image is Player1st.png in GameScene

And in StoreScene I need away to change the value of Player in Gamescene from Player1st.png to Player2nd.png In my Buy1 Function

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKQbF.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9vrn.png

Answer (score 0):

Why don't post the code instead image?

**UPDATE:**
Create a Player class on Player.swift:

```
class Player: SKSpriteNode {
    //some properties
    var maxLife: Int = 0

    init (image: String) {
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: image)
        super.init(texture: texture, color: nil, size: texture.size())
        //other setting position score etc
    }

    class func Level1() ->  Player {
        let player = Player(image: "Player1st.png")
        player.maxLife = 10
        return player
    }

    class func Level2() ->  Player {
        let player = Player(image: "Player2st.png")
        player.maxLife = 20
        return player
    }
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

StoreScene:

```
var player = Player.Level1()
func Buy1() {
    player = nil
    player = Player.Level2()
}
```

Comment: So you think I should make player a texture and not an SKSpriteNode? and if so why would that alow me to change it over the different game scenes?

Comment: Generally speaking, in case your player has any other properties, like lives points, score value, some state, etc, except a texture, it should be moved to separate class. And this class should be able to manage how player does look too in that case, probably process collisions and other game situations.

Comment: Ok, now I understood well your question,check my modification and let me know, I don't test it on compilator.

Comment: So what do i do if I already have a ton of physicsBodys and other stuff attatched to my player

Comment: @PianoManMike you can set physics and other stuff in init inside player class

Comment: What does init (image: String) { super.init(imageNamed: image)} do

Comment: Because it is giving me the error "Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'SKSpriteNode'"

Comment: Sorry you are right, I forgot that init(imageNamed) is a convenience init. Check now my update, may be there are other issue because I'm writing on windows pc and I can't test it